# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise xUnit not showing CodeLens for tests

Tags: visual-studio, xunit, codelens

I have VS2017 Enterprise, I develop .NET Core apps and use xUnit for testing. But I don't see CodeLens enabled for any of my tests.  I checked CodeLens settings, everything is turned on.  Is this an known issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug:

If you create a new file and write some tests, CodeLens will show up for the methods used in those tests. If you close Visual Studio and reopen it, CodeLens stops working.

I couldn't find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug as you can see on the [GitHub issue list for xunit.net](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1140).

It has been fixed in the **2.3 release** which is currently in beta. What I did was to check the "**include prerelease**" checkbox in the Visual Studio 2017 nuget package manager gui. Then I went to the updates tab within that dialog and installed the newest version (currently *2.3.0-beta4-build3742*). After that the CodeLens support started to work again